# JavaPackage object is not callable error for pydeequ constraint suggestion

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I'm getting a "JavaPackage object is not callable" error while trying to run the PyDeequ constraint suggestion method on databricks.

I have tried running this code on Apache Spark 3.1.2 cluster as well as Apache Spark 3.0.1 cluster but no luck.

`suggestionResult = ConstraintSuggestionRunner(spark).onData(df).addConstraintRule(DEFAULT()).run()`

`print(suggestionResult)`

Please refer to the second screenshot attached for the expanded error status.

[PyDeequ error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPyW7.png)

[Expanded PyDeequ error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr7Y5.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to combine some solutions [found here](https://github.com/awslabs/python-deequ/issues/1), as well as other solutions, to get past the above JavaPackage error in Azure Databricks. Here are the details, if helpful for anyone.

From [this link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazon.deequ/deequ), I downloaded the appropriate JAR file to match my Spark version. In my case, that was `deequ_2_0_1_spark_3_2.jar`. I then installed this file using the JAR type under Libraries in my cluster configurations.

The following then worked, ran in different cells in a notebook.

```
%pip install pydeequ
```

```
%sh export SPARK_VERSION=3.2.1
```

```
df = spark.read.load("abfss://container-name@account.dfs.core.windows.net/path/to/data")
```

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

import pydeequ

spark = (SparkSession
    .builder
    .getOrCreate())
```

```
from pydeequ.analyzers import *

analysisResult = AnalysisRunner(spark) \
                    .onData(df) \
                    .addAnalyzer(Size()) \
                    .addAnalyzer(Completeness("column_name")) \
                    .run()

analysisResult_df = AnalyzerContext.successMetricsAsDataFrame(spark, analysisResult)
analysisResult_df.show()
```